# Answering a question about multiple people with 'nor'

Tags: grammaticality

Someone asked a question in an email addressing a group (3 people). We had to respond in the negative. I am not clear on if this sentence is grammatically correct. The response I sent was:

```
A, B and I have not done it.
```

Now, logically if I use `and`, it sounds incorrect because I should be using an `or` to represent the fact that none of us have done it. For example, if it was two people, I would probably just say:

```
Neither A nor I have done it.
```

Instead of,

```
A and I have not done it.
```

So my question is:

1. Is there a way to write `sentence 1` in the same way as `sentence 2`?
2. Is `sentence 1` grammatically correct?

Comment: How about: *None of A, B nor I have done it*.  or *Speaking for A, B and I, none of us have done it*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either), "We can use *neither* as a conjunction with *nor*. It connects two or more negative alternatives."

Thus, in answer to your first question: Neither A nor B nor I have done it.
Alternatively: Neither A, B nor I have done it.

As for `sentence 1` being grammatically correct, yes it is (arguably clumsy) but correct.

Comment: The link you've provided doesn't actually explain what to do when there's more than one argument

Comment: @as4s4hetic - Sadly, this is true.